# Touch event in Breakout game in js

Tags: javascript, touch

I want to move paddle in Breakout game by touch. I have tried to make it as mouseover event but it does not work, altough it works when its used as mouseouver event:

```
document.addEventListener("touchmove", funcTouchMove, false)


function funcTouchMove(e) {
    var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    if(relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
    paddleX = relativeX - paddleWidth/2;
    }
}
```

Generally the aim is to touch the paddle, move right and left and play like with mouseover event. I would be grateful for ideas!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: I am aware of this.

Comment: It has a lot of example code in there, too.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by adding the following code :

```
document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMoveHandler, false);

function touchMoveHandler(event) { 
  var relativeX = event.touches[0].clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  if(relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
    paddleX = relativeX - paddleWidth/2;
  }
}
```

Update:
That code had the X touch reading way off to the left if the canvas isn't on the edge of the page. The following gets it to follow under your finger.

```
 var relativeX = event.touches[0].clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
```

Answer (score 0):

there are touchstart, touchend, touchmove events. Maybe you are looking for that ?

e.g. create a canvas fora joystick and attach these events like

```
canvasJoy.addEventListener("touchstart", inputStart, false);
canvasJoy.addEventListener("touchend", inputEnd, false);
canvasJoy.addEventListener("touchmove", inputMove, false);
```

Comment: I am aware of that, i simply don't know how to use, I have tried the code above.

Comment: attached a code example e.g. inputStart would be the function you call